# Bootstrap jumbotron not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use jumbotron in my Angular 2 sample project but its not all rendering anything .

I have used updated CDNs in index.html :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

my app.component looks like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `mytemplate.html`,
})
export class AppComponent  { 


}
```

mytemplate.html looks like

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>      
  </div>
  <p>This is some text.</p>      
  <p>This is another text.</p>      
</div>
```

but it is not getting rendered. It keeps showing loading appcomponent content here . Do i need to install any external packages to get it running . I am using Visual Studio Code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors @tinsten